# Having trouble using "sendto" in the lua sockets library

Tags: sockets, lua, udp, p2p, hole-punching

So I am trying to get a peer2peer matchmaking server going and I am having troubles with "sendto". I had some success with using "send" but then I couldn't do the hole punching step when the time came because it wouldn't switch peers to the other client for some reason. So now I am trying "sendto" but sendto cannot even send a message to the server.

Here is my code:

CLIENT:

```
local socket = require("socket")

local udp = socket.udp()
udp:setsockname("*", 0)
udp:settimeout(0)

--For server_ip I have also tried "localhost", "192.168.1.3", "127.0.0.1", and "127.0.0.0"
--none of them work. :(
local server_ip, server_port = "24.159.10.150", 30672

udp:sendto("FOO", server_ip, server_port)`
```

SERVER:

```
local socket = require("socket")

local udp = socket.udp()
udp:setsockname('*', 30672)
udp:settimeout(0)

while true do
    local data, ip, port = udp:receivefrom()
    if data ~= nil then
        break;
    end
end
print("SUCCESS!!")
```

Comment: can you try add sleep for few msec after sendto or turn one some timeout. Also may be check out your firewall. Because this code works for me with `127.0.0.1`

Comment: So I added 1000 ms of timeout...here is something weird though; it's not actually waiting though...I've tried basically every IP I can think of to try to send a message to the server...but whenever I "print" it keeps saying "nil No such host is know." The only thing I am doing in my firewall is port forwarding to my local ip traffic from that port (30672) but even when I am not forwarding traffic on that port it still does the same thing.

I am using version 3.0-rc1 if that helps...but I can't change versions as I am using corona to write my app and it comes pre-installed...

Comment: Can you try use tcp instead? Maybe it will show you any network problems.